# Difference in surface temperature between the Northwest Atlantic and Northeast Atlantic

Tags: ocean, oceanography, temperature, ocean-currents

Why is the surface waters in the Northwest Atlantic Ocean colder than the surface waters of the Northeast Atlantic Ocean?

Comment: one reason for this is the dominant wind direction,the wind blows from west and moves the hot surface water from west to east.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main reason is that the [Gulf Stream](https://www.livescience.com/26273-gulf-stream.html) transports warm surface water from the tropics, driven by the thermohaline circulation. The tropical [trade winds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade_winds) push surface water towards Western Atlantic and build up stress. Further north the dominant wind direction is towards the east. The [Coriolois force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force) also helps to move the warm water masses towards the east.

The [Labrador Current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labrador_Current), on the other hand, brings cold water down West Atlantic Ocean. The thermohaline turnover is further south in West Atlantic Ocean.

[image: Wikipedia RetAndr data from http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/image/2minrelief.html]